# How to deal with time in C++?

Tags: c++, time

Basically I need to write a program that will ask the user to enter arrival and departure time in the 24 hour format and it needs to calculate the difference between them.
I know how to do everything else, but i'm not sure how to make it so that it lets you enter the time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Doing a bit of online research, what resources have you found for C++ time handling? Just to make it clear, just asking a very basic question that doesn't indicate any research at all is just going to get you downvoted and the question closed here. Put some effort into solving the problem yourself first, only then you are really welcome to ask here!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve it, file for example showing us a [mre] of your own attempt together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: @vll, C++ definitely has utilities for parsing times.

Comment: For anything regarding time : use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono. It will prevent you from creating a lot of bugs with time boundaries (day boundaries, leap years etc). @vII C++20 has support for that : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::get_time` to parse the input into a `std::tm` structure. You can use `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t` to convert the `std::tm` object into a time point. You can subtract the time points to calculate the difference.

In C++20, you may streamline the code using `std::chrono::parse`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Validate your input with a regex like this [regex time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format/7536768).
2. Use [Posix time](https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) to create arrival and departure objects.
3. Use `diffTime` to get the difference. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867135/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-times-in-c)